# Some of glyphicons are not rendered, why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Can anyone explain me why I don't get some of glyphicon rendered (see the screenshot)? How can I test it?
[image: ScreenShot]

Edit: Everthing works great till today.
Edit2: jsfiddle added in comment

Solved: There is a bug in BootstrapCDN. Don't use it if you want above glyphicons.

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/DBu4u/1/` first glyphicon-lock is not rendered

Comment: The host of that CDN needs to be contacted, looks like Bootplys. Host the fonts and css locally if you don't want to be bothered with this.

Comment: I've already done it. Ver. of css and font files are inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Glyphicons is basically an additional font. so any character in glyphicon font file is no different than the letter a or b.

so inorder to display all characters, the glyphicon font file has to include the character you are referring to.

in another words check the glyphicon font file, and replace it if necessary.

another thing to consider might be to try a different browser. ie I know that firefox might not show font data properly when your font file is located at your computer (not remote)

Comment: How can I do it? In Chrome Console>Network>http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff>Preview I have only ABCDEF...etc

Comment: @RobM, tested your fiddle in Chrome and lock icon did not show.  In IE on Win8.1, it does show.   Certainly seems like a browser issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, using bootstrap 3 with less. I solved it by changing

content: "\e046";

to

content: "\1f4f7";

in case of the camera-glyphicon.
Might it be an encoding problem?

Comment: My lock icon is set to content: "\1f512";   No seeing it on IE but I can see it on Chrome.  Looks like a browser issue?